# How to get the largest value from NSArray containing dictionaries?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, key-value-coding

How do you get the largest value from an NSArray with dictionaries?

Lets say I have NSArray containing dictionaries with keys "age", "name", etc.
Now I want to get the record with the highest age.
Is this possible with some KVC magic? Or do I have to iterate through and do it the "manual" way?

I've tried with something similar to this:

```
int max = [[numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue];
```

Comment: if you need largest value of AGE... use  @max.age

Comment: Man, I sometimes wish we had something like [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) in Cocoa....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unless "intValue" is a key in your dictionary the key path won't do much good.

If it is the max age you are after you should use `@"@max.age"` (on the dictionary) to get it. The same goes for any other key in your dictionary.

```
[myDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"@max.age"];
```

If `numbers` is an array of values you could use `@"@max.self"` as the key path to get the largest value.

```
[myArrayOfNumbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"];
```

Comment: I am using your second line to get max element from my NSMutableArray (which contains all NSNumber objects inside) and I get this error:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFNumber 0x1dd44bc0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key max.'
Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry. I assumed it would behave as NSPredicate and use `self` when nothing else was specified. The correct second example would be `[myArrayOfNumbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"];` (answer updated)

Comment: I thought you will propose this solution, but really strange thing is that this updated solution DOESN'T WORK for me neither. I get the same error message like before.

Comment: Works for me, mutable or immutable. 
    `NSArray *numbers = @[ @3, @5, @2.5, @(-5) ];
    NSMutableArray *mutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:numbers];
    
    NSNumber *largestValue = [numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"];
    NSNumber *largestValueFromMutable = [mutable valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"];` Gives correct result and no crashes.

Comment: Arrrrgh! Sorry David for time I took you. I'm officially blind. I was constantly writing: valueForKeyPath:@"max.self" instead of valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self". (facepalm) Sorry and thank you once more! :)

Comment: Heads up if anyone's having trouble here: you need to call `valueForKeyPath:` not `valueForKey:`.

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly there, you just need to specify the exact field you want from which you want the max value:

```
NSInteger max = [[numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.age"] integerValue];
```

I took the liberty to modify your `int`s to `NSInteger`s, just in case somebody wants to use this code on both iOS and OS X.

Comment: This is a really good answer :) and it's different enough from the accepted answer to warrant an up vote